# Optimization problem of connection between nodes

Tags: python, math, optimization, probability

I have a problem that I am struggling to solve efficiently. I have 2 sets of nodes, A_1, ... A_m and B_1,... B_m. Each node from one set can be connected to a node from the other set with a given constant probability p. Then, what I want is to have the maximum links between the set A and the set B under the condition that there is one and only one node remaining between each single node of A and B.
For example if A_i is connected to B_j and B_j', then we have either to remove the link with either B_j or B_j'.

The successful link between A_i and B_j can be stored in a matrix where M_{ij} = 1 if there is a link between A_i and B_j, 0 if not.
This matrix can for example be simulated by the given code for a matrix dimension 5 and a probability 0.7 of successful link (in python):

```
import numpy as np

m = 5
proba = 0.7
M = np.random.choice([0, 1], size=(m, m), p=[1 - proba, proba])
```

This can give for example the matrix:

```
M =
[[0 1 0 1 0]
 [1 1 1 0 1]
 [1 1 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0]
 [1 1 1 1 1]]
```

What I want is to implement the transformation on this matrix that satisfies the condition of maximum one link between nodes while maximizing the number of links. This transformation convert M into M_2.

Here's the condition on M_2:
In the end, there is  k<= m links between the set A and the set B as each node of A can in fine connect to only one single node (or zero) of the the set of B.
This translate in terms of matrix into a transformation from M to M_2 where M_2_{ij} is equal either to M_{ij} or 0. If M_2_{i0,j0} = 1 then M_2_{i, j0} = 0 and M'_{i0, j} = 0 for all i, j != i0, j0. It means that there is only one (or zero) non zero term per row and per column.

It is easy to remove any terms in a row if one is already equal to one. The hard part of what I want my code to do is to maximize the number of non-zero terms of the matrix M_2 while respecting the conditions on the matrix M_2.

I've managed to do painfully the "automatic reduction part" where if you find a row with only one non-zero term, you remove the non-zero terms of the associated column and conversely. I've done it recursively, until the transformed matrix stays the same (The code is at the end, and is quite complicated to understand, because I think that I've not found the elegant way to do it...)

With this code there is some improvements:

```
M_2' = 
[[0 1 0 0 0]
 [1 0 1 0 1]
 [1 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0]
 [1 0 1 0 1]]
```

There are less non-zero terms compared to M in this matrix but still, it does not respect the conditions.

What I want is to automatically do the final step to find the matrix M_2 which by hand should look like this:

```
M_2 = 
[[0 1 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1]]
```

But I have no idea how to automatically and efficiently do such optimization... Anyone have ideas how to realize that?

Thank you in advance.

Paul

The code for the straightforward transformation that gave me M_2' is the following (if you have any improvement for a more pythonic or efficient way to write it, I'd be happy to see it):

```
def remove_straightforward_terms(M):
    """Transform the matrix M by removing a maximum of non-zero terms."""

    # Index of the non-zero (=1) terms:
    ind_i, ind_j = np.where(M == 1)

    # Remove automatically some terms:
    new_ind_i, new_ind_j = automatic_remove_straightforward(ind_i, ind_j)

    # Rebuild the matrix using this terms
    return build_matrix_non_zero(M, new_ind_i, new_ind_j)


def build_matrix_non_zero(M, ind_i, ind_j):
    """Rebuild the matrix using non-zero terms indices."""
    M_2 = np.zeros(M.shape, dtype=int)
    for ind, val in np.ndenumerate(ind_i):
        M_2[ind_i[ind], ind_j[ind]] = 1
    return M_2


def automatic_remove_straightforward(ind_i, ind_j):
    """Recursively remove the terms from ind_i and ind_j."""
    ind_j_int_2 = []
    ind_i_int_2 = []
    while len(ind_i) != len(ind_i_int_2) and len(ind_j) != len(ind_j_int_2):
        if len(ind_i_int_2) != 0:
            # Necessary for entering the while loop...
            ind_i = ind_i_int_2
            ind_j = ind_j_int_2
        # If there is only one non zero term for a given row, remove the other corresponding terms from the column.
        ind_i_int_2, ind_j_int_2 = remove_indices_straightforward(ind_i, ind_j)
        # If there is only one non zero term for a given column, remove the other corresponding terms from the row.
        ind_j_int_2, ind_i_int_2 = remove_indices_straightforward(
            ind_j_int_2, ind_i_int_2)
    return ind_i, ind_j


def remove_indices_straightforward(ind_i, ind_j):
    """Remove the non-zero terms automatically.

    Let's consider i is the column and j the row"""

    unique_i, counts_i = np.unique(ind_i, return_counts=True)

    # Record all the indices that will be removed (it correspond to removing non-zero terms)
    remove_ind = []

    for ind, val_counts in np.ndenumerate(counts_i):
        if val_counts == 1:
            # If a term is in ind_i is only here once (it is alone on its line).
            val_i = unique_i[ind]

            # We find its position in the list ind_i
            index_ind_i = np.where(ind_i == val_i)[0]

            # We find the correspond row of the list ind_j
            val_j = ind_j[index_ind_i]

            # We find the indices of all the non-zero terms share the same row.
            indices_ind_j = np.where(ind_j == val_j)[0]

            # We record all but the one that was found in the first place
            indices_ind_j = indices_ind_j[indices_ind_j != index_ind_i]
            # and put them in the remove_ind
            remove_ind = np.concatenate((remove_ind, indices_ind_j))
    # We remove the indices that we don't want anymore
    new_ind_j = np.delete(ind_j, remove_ind)
    new_ind_i = np.delete(ind_i, remove_ind)
    return new_ind_i, new_ind_j


M_2 = remove_straightforward_terms(M)
```

**EDIT:
Using the solution proposed by btilly, here is how to obtain the desired matrix:**

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
from networkx.algorithms import bipartite

m = 5
p = 0.7
def connecting(m, p):
    G_1 = nx.bipartite.random_graph(m, m, p)
    top_nodes = {n for n, d in G_1.nodes(data=True) if d['bipartite'] == 0}
    A = nx.bipartite.hopcroft_karp_matching(G_1, top_nodes)
    M = np.zeros((m, m), dtype=int)
    for node_1, node_2 in A.items():
        if node_1 < m:
            M[node_1, node_2 - m] = 1
    return M
```

Comment: The phrase to look for is "maximum bipartite matching" and the [Hopcroft-Karp algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopcroft%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm) is the answer you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, it really helped. I've edited to put the code to obtain the matrix m using this technique and networkx